# Xamarin VS2022 not getting signing identity

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build a release I have the created the Apple Distribution and Apple Development Cert but I am not seeing them in the VS2022 just this automatic one listed. I  was thinking I should see the name and then this error would stop.

[image]

[image]

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.   GuidelinesApp.iOS

[image]

Comment: Did you connect your apple account to visual studio?

Comment: No is that something new with vs2022?

Comment: No, it was 2019 also. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/apple-account-management?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes I have the account setup in that options section but I dont see the  cert or the provision profile

Comment: should I see one in this section?

Comment: You are on a mac, right?

Comment: No I am on a PC that is pair to a mac